# Read/write in a file asynchronically on a webserver

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, request, fs

I have a express server running. One of the `post` routes does a http request , with each of those requests I'd like to log data into a file. The data that I'll be logging is extracted from the data that is being sent.

Data that I'm sending is in xml format, so I parse it first with xml2js module.
After that I read the file so I can append my new JSON and after that I write the result back into my file. I'm using `jsonfile` module for reading and writing into my json file.

What I'm currently worried about is when 2 requests come at the same time.

My read/write will be async and I'll get loss of data. I believe the problem will be more obvious as the file starts to grow and functions take more time to finish.

So how do I handle this?
I'm absolutely against using `readfilesync` and `writefilesync`.

```
 ...
  app.post('/testapi', function (req, res) {

   request({
       "url": 'https://webservice.com',
       "method": "POST",
       "body" :req.body
     },
       function(err, response, body){
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        } else {
            res.send(body);
            logSomeData(req.body);
        }
    });
});

function logSomeData(body) {
    var currYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
            currMonth = new Date().getMonth(),
            fileName = __dirname + '/logs/' + currYear + '_' + currMonth + '.json';

    parseString(body, function (err, result) {
        jsonfile.readFile(fileName, function(err, obj) {

            var logData = {test : "test"};
            obj.push(logData);

            jsonfile.writeFile(fileName, obj, {spaces: 2}, function(err) {
                console.error(err)
            });
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: This is why people use databases instead of JSON files. They handle all the problems of file locking for you.

Comment: @Quentin My company uses Oracle DB. Oracle does have nodejs driver for it but installation is still clunky and the driver is rather fresh. Is there some other light DB that could serve for this purpose and is it even worth it?

Comment: SQLite springs to mind. And yes. Yes it is.

Comment: @Quentin Would a logger like winston be useful in this situation? Do loggers solve read/write async problem?

Answer (score 2):

This sounds like a job for a database, as database engines are typically more adept at handling multiple connections - ie adding records 'on-the-fly' as needed.

Then later you can suck out the info into a text file if you like... or just apply SQL queries to the database to get back the information you really need.

Determining what kind of database to use is probably beyond the scope of this question, and will depend on your needs and resources.

Answer (score -2):

You can use some sort of middleware that will log the contents to a file, but nodejs might have some performance issues while reading and parsing large XML files, in my company we are parsing large XML files(150-140MB), for a single node app it will lead to a complete server freeze and you will not be able to make any other request to the same service.

What i suggest if you plan to work with a lot of xml parsing is to make some other Node\JAVA service that will make the logging\parsing, so you can let your main node server to be available for other requests.

Also, i suggest parsing your XML files (especially large ones) with some sort of XML Streaming library, so it will parse them in streams instead of loading it all in memory.